# Inverting the sum of a circulant and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there an efficient way of (numerically) solving a linear system, where the matrix is a sum of circulant and diagonal matrices?
I need to solve a linear system of the form

(V+D)x=y

where

- V is a circulant matrix, symmetric, positive definite, and invertible, but with eigenvalues spanning a wide range.
- D is a diagonal matrix, the values on the diagonal varying between 0 and 1.

Either component can be easily inverted, D directly and V using Fourier technique, but their sum is not. I do get a solution via conjugate-gradient iteration, with V+I as preconditioner, but the convergence is painfully slow (without preconditioning it is horrible).  I would need to solve this kind of system for thousands of times, with V always staying the same but D and y changing. The size of the matrix is of the order of 10^5.

Is there a general technique for solving this kind of linear systems, or alternatively, can someone suggest a better preconditioner?

Comment: If either matrix is low-rank (or if the diagonal matrix has a lot of repeating values), the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) would be useful

Comment: Do you mean $VV^T=I$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz circulant matrices [are defined as is explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)

Comment: @Kosmoelina: $V$ is circulant and symmetric - so all off-diagonal elements are identical, similarly all diagonal elements?

Comment: @user376343:  Yes, that is true for V.  The diagonal elements of D vary.

Comment: How wildly the values of D are changing?